# An error has occurred: Error connecting to the server: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I have installed Postgres 9.5 version using entripeseDB in my Linux system.

And connected to Postgres using pgadmin3 and created database and table.
then I am able to get data from laravel php application.

then my system shudown unexpectedly.

On the restart  I am not able to connect the Postgres server.

The error is:

> Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist.

What could be the reasons for this? And how can I resolve this?

Comment: Thats very strange... have you changed the name of the super user account?  Is there another super user account that you've added?

Comment: I didn't change. on installation process only postgress super user is created and added password to it

Answer (score 0):

It's odd that this has happened without you doing anything to remove the superuser.  I'm going to answer this as if the error you are getting is correct, but I suspect something else is happening.

If the error message is to be believed then the main super user (`postgres`) nolonger exists in your db.  From what you've said this is the only super user so to get it back you will need to start the postgresql server in single user mode.

I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.04 with postgresql 9.5.  Directories might be different on your system

---

1. Stop the server

   `sudo service postgres stop`
2. Log into the OS user that owns the database (for me that's also called `postgres`).  I use:

   ```
   sudo -u postgres bash
   ```
3. Run the PostgreSQL server in single user mode.  You will need to specify the config directory for the cluster and the database name (my cluster is 9.5/main and the db is also called `main`) This should give you the backend prompt:

   ```
   /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/postgres --single -D /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/

   PostgreSQL stand-alone backend 9.5.4
   backend>
   ```
4. From the backend prompt add a new user called `postgres` with the `superuser` privilage:

   ```
   backend> create user postgres superuser;
   backend>
   ```
5. Exit the single-user mode.  I press `ctrl-d`.
6. log back in as yourself.  For me that's just:

   ```
   exit
   ```
7. Start the server:

   ```
   sudo service postgres start
   ```

---

To find which user postgresql runs as.  Make sure the server is still running (ie, if you have stopped it then `sudo service postgres start`).  Then look for the running process:

```
ps -ef | grep postgres
```

For me this gives the following.  Notice the left hand column for me says `postgres`.  This is the OS user that is running my database cluster.

```
postgres 25536     1  0 16:40 ?        00:00:01 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
postgres 25539 25536  0 16:40 ?        00:00:00 postgres: checkpointer process
postgres 25540 25536  0 16:40 ?        00:00:00 postgres: writer process
postgres 25541 25536  0 16:40 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal writer process
postgres 25542 25536  0 16:40 ?        00:00:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
postgres 25543 25536  0 16:40 ?        00:00:00 postgres: stats collector process
couling   32550 23363  0 21:35 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto postgres
```

Sometimes this user won't be set up to log in, so if your OS user is called `postgres` then try using:

```
sudo -u postgres bash
```

---

For the database name you need any valid DB name in your cluster so if you can't remember your DB name then try `postgres` or `template0`.

Comment: Yes.I also installed postgress-xc  before postgressql. Now removed postgress-xc , then restarted the system. Now I am able to connect postgress from pgadmin.

Comment: Thank you, Actually I installed Postgres by follwoing http://tutorialforlinux.com/2014/02/20/how-to-install-latest-postgresql-9-x-on-linux-mint-16-petra-3264bit-linux-easy-guide/. The Postgres installed in my system at /opt/PostgresSQl/9, and installed ph5psql. if I want to see my Postgres users and DBS from command line , I tried login from console by sudo su -postgress, but I am not able to see my Postgres user and Db. can u tell me how can I  do that.

Comment: I've added a little more